# How to avoid delay of webservice(ASIHTTPRequest) response in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, asihttprequest

In my iPhone app handling web service for storing and retrieving data.Now i am using the following code for web service handling.

```
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];

[request setPostValue:@"1" forKey:@"id"];

[request setTag:100];

[request setDelegate:self];

[request startAsynchronous];
```

By this code i got response in 'requestFinished' method.My problem is web service response is very delay(depends upon internet speed).How to make response from web service very fast?Please help me.

Comment: Thats something which you cannot control. I guess you are blessed that you got this problem while developing, most of us develop on very fast office network and when client uses app on all types of network issues  start appearing. You can fetch data in background so that ui does not hang.

Comment: @amar,You are absolutely right!!How to call webservice in background??

Comment: use dispatch queue http://www.raywenderlich.com/4295/multithreading-and-grand-central-dispatch-on-ios-for-beginners-tutorial  and one suggestion ASIHttp is no longer being maintained migrate to afnetworking it will do things in background for you

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to send json objects by post method..delay is depend on your server(how fast it handle request and response back) but i suggest you to use progress bar and blocks to handle network request..

```
loadingHUD = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
loadingHUD.labelText = NSLocalizedString(@"Downloading", nil);
loadingHUD.mode=MBProgressHUDModeAnnularDeterminate;
 NSString *documentDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask,YES) lastObject];
// Add your filename to the directory to create your saved file location
NSString* destPath = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[fileName stringByAppendingString:@".mov"]];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:mainURL];
AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"POST" path:postURL parameters:postRequest];
NSLog(@"postRequest: %@", postRequest);

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
operation.outputStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:destPath append:NO];



[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
 {

         NSLog(@"Successfully downloaded file to %@",[[NSString alloc] initWithData:operation.responseData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]);

     // Give alert that downloading successful.
     NSLog(@"Successfully downloaded file to %@", destPath);

     NSLog(@"response: %@", operation.responseString);  // Give alert that downloading successful.

     // [self.target parserDidDownloadItem:destPath];

     loadingHUD.detailsLabelText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %i%%",@"Downloading",100];
     [loadingHUD hide:TRUE];

     [DBHelper savePurchaseId:fileName];
     [self movieReceived];

 }
    failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
 {
     // Give alert that downloading failed
     NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);

     // [self.target parserDidFailToDownloadItem:error];
     [loadingHUD hide:TRUE];

 }];
[operation setDownloadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesWritten, long long totalBytesWritten, long long totalBytesExpectedToWrite)
 {
     // Progress
     progress = ((float)totalBytesWritten) / fileSize;
     loadingHUD.progress = progress;
          }];
[operation start];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

We cant control the internet speed due to the different network provider or environment when the client is using your app.

But you can put your web-services to run in background without effecting your main function.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
   //code for webservices calling

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
       //functions after your webservices done, for example reload the table or hide the loading bar.

    });
});
```